# Django1.4 form.is_valid() always returning True

Tags: django

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField(required = False)
    message = forms.CharField()
```

python shell:

```
>>> f = ContactForm({'subject': 'Hello'})
>>> f.is_valid()
>>> True
```

It's not what I expected.

Comment: about the python shell:i mean: 1.create an object:f = ContactForm({'subject': 'Hello'}) 2.call function is_valid() 3.it return true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not answer but I don't see such behavior. In my case form is not valid.
This is from django shell,

```
>>> class ContactForm(forms.Form):
...     subject = forms.CharField()
...     email = forms.EmailField(required = False)
...     message = forms.CharField()
... 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> cf = ContactForm({'subject': "hello"})
>>> cf.is_valid()
False
>>> cf.errors
{'message': [u'This field is required.']}
```